# How to remove outliers from data frame in R?

Tags: r, outliers

I have a data frame with 25 Variables. I want to remove the outliers from it.

I have searched SO forum and found that there are custom kind of solutions people are proposing for different posts.

Is there some standard R function that removes the outliers from the data?

Here are two functions I found from search. How good they are OR is there some standard same kind of better solution to achieve this in R in any package.

OR a function which I pass one column as argument & it returns outliers removed data.

**remove_outliers:**
[Link 1](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/molaR/versions/3.2/topics/remove_outliers)

**Removing outliers - quick & dirty:**
[Link 2](http://rpubs.com/Mentors_Ubiqum/removing_outliers)

**EDIT**

The data in my data frame contains continuous data from two sources i.e. weather and ground. From weather, the predictors are temperature, humidity, wind, rain, solar radiation. And from ground are groundwater and soil moisture. I want to find a relation between soil moisture and other variables. I am analysing data using different models. Now I want to se the results after removing the outliers from data.

**EDIT**
I used and edited code from one of the tutorials I added reference above. It's working fine when there are some outliers in the data. But it raises error when there are no. How to correct this.

**Here is code:**

```
outlier_rem<-Data_combined #data-frame with 25 var, few have outliers

#removong outliers from the column

outliers <- boxplot(outlier_rem$var1, plot=FALSE)$out
#print(outliers)
#ol<-outlier_rem[which(outlier_rem$var1 %in% outliers),]
ol<-outlier_rem[-which(outlier_rem$var1 %in% outliers),]

dim(ol)
boxplot(ol)
```

**Here is error msg when ol returns 0 vale.**

```
> dim(ol)
[1]  0 25
> boxplot(ol)
no non-missing arguments to min; returning Infno non-missing arguments to max; returning -InfError in plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, log = log, yaxs = pars$yaxs) : 
  need finite 'ylim' values
```

Comment: There's no standard definition of "outlier." It all depends on your data and what you plan to do with it. Without a more precise definition, this question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I add more detail in OP

Comment: That still doesn't make it clear what an "outlier" is in your case. Are you worried that the data you are getting was measured incorrectly? Or why do you want to drop any of your data at all?

Comment: I don't want to drop it from original set. I have same data from two different places. But results in the analysis are very different from each other. Good for prediction at one place while not on other. I want to see after removing outliers how results appear then. Outlier is a value in my case that's far from normal distribution of data. Like moisture is evenly distributed then few values all of sudden far away. May sensor misread OR something else. So to see the results without those outliers or un-usually far from majority of values variables.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Chebyshev's inequality as a criterion for dropping extreme values. It has the advantage that it holds true in many probablility distributions. The rule states tha no more than 1/k^2 of the values can be more than k standard deviations away from the mean. For example:

```
> x <- rchisq(1000, 13)
> 
> mean(x)
[1] 12.83906
> sd(x)
[1] 4.93234
> 
> Ndesv <- 5
> 
> x[x > (mean(x) + Ndesv * sd(x))]
[1] 38.7575
> 
> Conf <- (1 - 1 / Ndesv^2)
> print(Conf)
[1] 0.96
>
```

Hope it helps you.